# Is my procedure all right to show the double integral as a single integral type ? And is it allowed without any restriction that we can do so?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Below was the problem : i have shown **what i did by by parts integration** **but i read that it needs a bit caution as its the same thing as switching the order of integrals and both integral needs to converge according to fubini theorem**, if that is so then is there any step which i should have not written when i was doing the by parts or **should have written is only valid if both converges**? The problem: $$\int_0^1\int_x^1 f'(t)\, dt\, dx =\int_0^1 xf'(x)\, dx. $$ My approach:  By IBP: we get $$\int_0^1\int_1^x f'(t)\, dt\, dx = \left[x\int_x^1 f'(t) \, dt\right]_0^1 - \int_0^1 (-x)f'(x)\, dx. $$ [**the first limits is zero after putting the values hence  proved**]

Comment: This is pretty difficult to read. Some dashes mean $1$, and some might mean "derivative" I think? Please write it out using MathJax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Oh sure @DanielP .

Comment: Those who donwvoted please tell what should i make clear more?